# try yield finally - did we raise an exception?

Tags: python, exception, yield, finally

### TL;DR

Is it possible to find out in a finally clause whether there's an outstanding uncaught exception?

### Background

I want to iterate over items to do some relatively expensive processing on them, which is likely to break and raise an exception. So I'd like to save my place.
But saving state is also pretty expensive - so I'd rather not do it every single time, **just when there's an exception in the code I yield to**.

I'm imagining something vaguely shaped like:

```
def get_things(my_iterator):
    for items in my_iterator:
        try:
            yield item
        finally:
            if something_went_wrong():  # magic oracle function for failure
                save_state(item)
        continue_normal_processing()
```

but I don't know whether that's even possible. Notably, `except Exception:` doesn't raise anything, because the exception isn't in this function.

Comment: You mean *elsewhere* an exception is raised, outside of this generator? Then `try:`/`finally:` is not the right way to go about this; there is nothing to `try` here.

Comment: How would `yield` raise an exception? If an exception occurs on generating the next item, wouldn't that already be raised by the loop? Also, why not just use `except` instead of `finally` here?

Comment: *What exactly* is raising the exception? Is `my_iterator` a source of exceptions?

Comment: You should post the TD;DR part as the first sentence because that is displayed as a short-descriprion of this question to those who answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

... seems I was totally wrong about `except`'s behaviour.

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            yield i
        except Exception:
            print "Nope, this broke"
            raise


for x in f():
    print x
    if x == 2:
        raise IndexError
```

returns

```
0
1
2
Nope, this broke
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
IndexError
```

Comment: I did not expect this behaviour. Cool.

Comment: More information for the next person who's puzzled by this: the "Nope, this broke" prints during the garbage collection of the generator.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran this code sample on 2.7.12 and I'm not getting a print of "Nope, this broke".

Comment: @DanielStutzbach - To clarify, are you saying that this behaviour only occurs because `f()` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) function?

Comment: In python 3.8 it raises  `IndexError` without handling.

Answer (score 1):

This should be similar to what you want:

```
class CatchingExceptionsIterator:
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self.generator = generator
        self.error = None
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.error is None:
            return next(self.generator)
        else:
            error = self.error
            self.error = None
            return self.generator.throw(*error)
    __next__ = next
    def __exit__(self, ty, err, tb):
        if ty is not None:
            self.error = ty, err, tb
            return True
    def __iter__(self):
        return self


def f():
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            print("yield")
            yield i
            print("returnFomYield")
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()


c = CatchingExceptionsIterator(f())
for i in c:
    with c:
        print(i)
        if i == 5:
            nameerror
```

It must be adjusted to fit the exact usecase.
The output is:

```
yield
0
returnFomYield
yield
1
returnFomYield
yield
2
returnFomYield
yield
3
returnFomYield
yield
4
returnFomYield
yield
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "withiteration.py", line 27, in f
    yield i
  File "withiteration.py", line 39, in <module>
    nameerror
NameError: name 'nameerror' is not defined
yield
6
returnFomYield
yield
7
returnFomYield
yield
8
returnFomYield
yield
9
returnFomYield
```

An additional finally clause would also be executed.

> Is it possible to find out in a finally clause whether there's an outstanding uncaught exception?

Why? You could use `except`. Explain this in more detail.